# Wordpress Comments Section Not Showing

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm at a loss to for a solution to my comments section not showing on my single post page. I've noticed that this page is not displaying any of the code below the post and tags sections. Would someone be willing to look at the code in the admin for me? I imagine it could be something simple to identify, as the site is organized nicely.

This is the only way I think the problem could be solved.

UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE.  Here's Single.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php include ('page_header.php'); ?>
    <?php include ('page_navigation.php'); ?>       


    <div id="page-content" class="clearfix">

        <div id="content-container" class="clearfix">

            <div id="main-content">

                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php if ( get_option('minimax_post_layout') == 'head-three' ) { ?>

                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?><em>Posted on <?php the_time('D, M d, Y') ?></em></h2>     
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                        <div class="post-item-thumb-<?php echo get_option('minimax_post_layout'); ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumb_post_3'); ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>                                                                                                  

                    <?php } else { ?>

                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                        <div class="post-item-thumb-<?php echo get_option('minimax_post_layout'); ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumb_post_2'); ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>                                                                      
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?><em>Posted on <?php the_time('D, M d, Y') ?></em></h2>     

                    <?php } ?>                                                              

                    <?php the_content(); ?>

                    <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '<br /><p>', '</p>'); ?>   

                    <?php include ('post_related.php'); ?>

                    <div id="post-indexing"> <?php the_tags('<strong>Tagged as</strong> ',', ','+'); ?><br /><strong>Categorized as</strong> <?php the_category(', ','single'); ?></div>                

                    <?php include ('post_author.php'); ?>   


                    <?php comments_template(); ?>               

                <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no pages matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </div><!-- end main-content -->

            <?php include ('sidebar_post.php'); ?>  

        </div><!-- end content-container -->


        <?php include ('footer_columns_posts.php'); ?>


    </div><!-- end page-content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Also, here's the comments.php page:

```
<div id="comments">
<?php // Do not delete these lines
if (!empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) && 'comments.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
    die ('Please do not load this page directly. Thanks!');

if (!empty($post->post_password)) { // if there's a password
    if ($_COOKIE['wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH] != $post->post_password) {  // and it doesn't match the cookie
        ?>

        <p class="nocomments">This post is password protected. Enter the password to view comments.</p>

        <?php
        return;
    }
}

/* This variable is for alternating comment background */
$oddcomment = 'class="alt" ';
?>

<!-- You can start editing here. -->



<?php if ($comments) : ?>

<h2>Comments <span>(<?php comments_number('No Responses', 'One Response', '% Responses' );?

>)</span></h2>

<ul class="commentlist">
    <?php wp_list_comments('avatar_size=60&type=comment'); ?>
</ul>    

 <?php else : // this is displayed if there are no comments so far ?>

<?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>
    <!-- If comments are open, but there are no comments. -->

 <?php else : // comments are closed ?>
    <!-- If comments are closed. -->

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>


<?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>

<div id="respond">

<h3><?php comment_form_title( 'Leave a Reply', 'Leave a Reply to %s' ); ?></h3>
<div class="cancel-comment-reply">
<?php cancel_comment_reply_link(); ?>
</div>

<?php if ( get_option('comment_registration') && !$user_ID ) : ?>
<p>You must be <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php echo 
urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>">logged in</a> to post a comment.</p>
<?php else : ?>


<div id="post-comment" class="clearfix">

<form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" 
id="commentform">
<fieldset>
<?php if ( $user_ID ) : ?>

<p>Logged in as <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/profile.php"><?php echo
$user_identity; ?></a>. <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?
action=logout" title="Log out of this account">Log out &raquo;</a></p>

<?php else : ?>


<label for="author"><?php if ($req) echo "* "; ?>Your name:</label>
<input type="text" name="author" id="author" value="<?php echo $comment_author; ?>" size="22"
tabindex="1" />

<label for="email"><?php if ($req) echo "* "; ?>Mail (will not be published):</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $comment_author_email; ?>"
size="22" tabindex="2" />

<label for="url">Website</label>
<input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo $comment_author_url; ?>" size="22"
tabindex="3" />


<?php endif; ?>

<!--<p><small><strong>XHTML:</strong> You can use these tags: <code><?php echo allowed_tags(); ?
></code></small></p>-->

<label for="comment" class="comment">Your comment:</label>
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="comment" cols="61%" rows="10" 
tabindex="4"></textarea>

<input name="submit" type="submit" class="submit" alt="Submit Comment" id="submit" tabindex="5"
value="Submit Comment" />
<input type="hidden" class="hide" name="comment_post_ID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />

<?php comment_id_fields(); ?>
<?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div><!-- end post-comment -->
</div>
<?php endif; // If registration required and not logged in ?>


<?php endif; // if you delete this the sky will fall on your head ?>
</div>
```

Here is post_author.php

```
<?php if ( get_option('minimax_author') == 'yes' ) { ?>
<div id="author-desc" class="clearfix">
<?php the_author_image(); ?>
<h4>About the Author</h4>
<?php the_author_description(); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: single post page is single.php, and there is also comments.php

Comment: comments do not show up under the sidebar recent comments, nor when I go straight to the blog page, then click on "continue reading" page, which displays the single post page

Comment: Not sure it's good idea to post your credentials like this. Somebody can use it for bad.

Comment: Yeah.......I took a chance:)  Thanks for your concern though....

Comment: @RobMyrick Seriously dude, you need to change your password **immediately**. I've edited the user/pass out of the question. Don't ever do that again. I logged in and could've dumped your entire database of posts. Some people would do it just to teach you a lesson.

Comment: Thanks for the concern guys......credentials are changed.

Comment: Can you share your single.php and comments.php (if exists) ?

Comment: @RobMyrick , which page you can'T see comment form ?

Comment: It's the page after the "blog" page.  1. click on blog in top navigation on main site.  choose a post, then click, "continue reading".  The post shows great, but after the tag/categories, no code is being rendered.  You can even see that the bottom footer image is not displaying compared to the other pages.  The footer image is just the rounded corner white background that ends the page display. Nothing under that point is showing up

Comment: Also, I've checked every possible way that comments could be disabled, and everything is enabled for sure.  I check several ways to do this through searching Google.

Comment: @RobMyrick , are you sure, there is a `post_author.php` ? You are including it on single.php. If there is, can you share it's content?

Comment: Yes, there is a post_author.php. I am posting now.

Comment: Can you remove `<?php include ('post_author.php'); ?>` line from single.php, temporarily ? If it's work, your post_author.php file isn't in your theme's folder.

Comment: Hi, Eray.....dude you are da man!  Why did that work?   And why would post_author.php have anything to do with it?

Comment: post_author.php and single.php must be in same directory. I mean, they must be in `wp-content/themes/themename/` . Copy your post_author.php to that directory and add this `<?php include ('post_author.php'); ?>` to your single.php file. If it's work, i'll post this an answer, so you can accept it :)

Comment: I'm guessing not having the post_author.php file cause PHP to go nuts and not display additional content on the page?

Comment: Where is your `post_author.php` file ? You said, *there is* .

Comment: I just checked the server, both files are in the location you mentioned.  Completely weird, although removing the code snippet you mentioned before already did the trick.  Maybe it's already solved?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6945/discussion-between-rob-myrick-and-eray)

Comment: BUt this time there isn't POST AUTHOR section . You can copy all content of `post_author.php`'s and then paste it instead of this line : `<?php include ('post_author.php'); ?>`

Comment: It disappeared again when I manually added the code?  Is there possible conflict elsewhere?

Comment: OK can you delete `<?php the_author_image(); ?>` line ? (From just you add manually)

Comment: OK.  A step in the right direction.  Now "About the Author" displays, but it's just plain content, not adding any value

Comment: @RobMyrick come to chat : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6945/discussion-between-rob-myrick-and-eray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any function like `the_author_image()` in Wordpress. So, you have to remove

`<?php the_author_image(); ?>`

line from your `post_author.php`. If you want to show author image , Wordpress getting avatars from Gravatar. You can use [get_avatar()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar) to display author's Gravatar.

```
echo get_avatar(get_the_author_id());
```

**In shortly**, use this :

```
<?php echo get_avatar(get_the_author_id()); ?>
```

instead of this :

`<?php the_author_image(); ?>`